# Unable to replace with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've notifications system on my app and document title is updating with addition of total number of notifications just like facebook and twitter. I want it to remove number with parantheses just after user's click to a button.

```
document.title = dc.replace(/\(([^)][\d]+)\)/, "");
```

this is what I use but it's not working. i'm not that good with regex. All I want to do is replace `(10) My Website's Homepage` with `My Website's Homepage`on click.

thanks.

Comment: Your first sentence makes little to no sense.

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get an error message? I just tried your code and it works.

dc = "(10) My Website's Homepage"
document.title = dc.replace(/\(([^)][\d]+)\)/, "");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant for the `[^)]` to be a lookahead instead of an actual character, and that the `+` quantifier is supposed to go outside the parentheses that groups this lookahead to the digit. That is, you're trying to say:

```
* Find an opening bracket
* Followed by one or more digits that aren't closing brackets
* Followed by a closing bracket
```

But notice how the second sentence, although valid, is redundant? A digit is *never* a closing bracket.  All you need is therefore:

```
/\(\d+\)/
```

Comment: @AliDemirci, check out my answwer

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
document.title=dc.replace(/\(\d+\)\s/,"");
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/x6BKD/